# Expected rth smallest average height of adjacent people randomly placed in a line

Tags: statistics

Suppose we have $n$ people lined up in a random order, from position 1 to position $n$. We may assume that their heights $h$ are described by a normal distribution with a certain mean height $h_m$ and standard deviation $SD$.

If we wanted to know the expected value of the $r$th shortest person in the line, it would simply be the case of calculating the $r$th order statistic. An approximation is given by Blom (1958) as:

$h(r,n)=h_m+\Phi^{-1}(\frac{r-\alpha}{n-2\alpha+1})SD$

where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse normal probability function, with $\alpha=3/8$ or $\pi/8$.

Now, let's say we take each of the $n-1$ adjacent pairs of people in the line and average their heights. In other words, we take the people in positions 1 and 2 and calculate their average height, then for 2 and 3, ..., then for $n-1$ and $n$. Remember, the people in the line were placed in random positions to begin with.

From the new list of $n-1$ averages, is it possible to again determine the expected value of the $r$th smallest average? What is its value?

Appreciate the help in advance.

Reference:

Blom G. Statistical estimates and transformed beta-variables. Wiley; New York: 1958.

Comment: Somewhat messy: In 'averaging' data by using 'adjacent pairs', you use first and last of the original $n$ observations once and you use the rest twice. Why would you want to do such a thing?

Comment: The problem has a very specific (and useful) application, which I can't explain here with limited characters. I've made the analogy to people's heights just for the sake of simplicity. If it helps, we could consider the line of people to be a ring, so that we end up averaging the heights of the first and last person in the line - it doesn't make a lot of difference.

Comment: Best to try to tell us in the Question what's really going on. And yes, it would have helped to consider 'people in a ring'. (Maybe you would have had an un-deleted answer from @expiTTpizo.)

Comment: To be frank there is little need to explain the underlying problem because it is entirely analogous to that of people's heights.

Comment: I've made a scan of Blom for those who want to go more into depth: https://www.gwern.net/docs/statistics/1958-blom-orderstatistics.djvu